# expect is throwing an "AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal true"

Tags: automation, protractor, chai

I have an error with the expect on my tests

I'm getting this error

```
[08:41:37] E/launcher - expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal true
[08:41:37] E/launcher - AssertionError: expected { Object (browser_, then, ...) } to equal true
    at role.element.getText.then (/Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/tests/e2e/console_bdd/steps/manage_agents_steps.js:114:109)
    at elementArrayFinder_.then (/Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/node_modules/protractor/built/element.js:804:32)
    at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1376:14)
    at TaskQueue.execute_ (/Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3084:14)
    at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:3067:27)
    at asyncRun (/Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2927:27)
    at /Users/jburquez/akamai/ConsoleUI/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:668:7
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[08:41:37] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
[08:41:37] '<anonymous>' errored after 1.42 min
[08:41:37] Error in plugin "gulp-protractor"
Message:
    protractor exited with code 199
Details:
    domain: [object Object]
    domainThrown: true
```

And this is my code on the step

```
  Then('Validate role {editrole} is selected', { timeout:30 * 1000 }, (editrole) => {
    var agentRoles = element.all(by.repeater('ctrl.roles'));
    agentRoles.each((role) => {
      return role.element(by.xpath(".//div[@class='md-whiteframe-1dp outset inset']/md-checkbox")).getText()
      .then((roleSelected) => {
        if (editrole === roleSelected) {
          expect(element(".//div[@class='md-whiteframe-1dp outset inset']/md-checkbox").isSelected()).to.be.equal(true);
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

What i'm trying to do is verify if an element is checked so reading another suggestions I saw that `.isSelected()` is the best option for this, but i'm not sure why is throwing this error.

Hope you can help me!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to compare an Object to Boolean.
You have to resolve a promise to do that or else use 'eventually' if you are using 'chai' as your assert library. Sample below:

```
expect(element(".//div[@class='md-whiteframe-1dp outset inset']/md-checkbox").isSelected()).to.eventually.equal(true);
```

Or

```
element(".//div[@class='md-whiteframe-1dp outset inset']/md-checkbox").isSelected().then(function (select) {
    expect(select).to.be.true;
});
```

It takes a little while to figure out the right way of using expect with promises.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to look at async/await syntax. And also you can try to use `browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected)` here

```
Then('Validate role {editrole} is selected', { timeout:30 * 1000 }, async (editrole) => {
    const agentRoles = element.all(by.repeater('ctrl.roles'))
    expect(await agentRoles.count()).not.to.be(0)
    await browser.wait(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeSelected(
        element(by.cssContainingText('div.md-whiteframe-1dp.outset.inset md-checkbox', editrole))
    ), 10000, `Expected ${editrole} to be selected`);
});
```